# Reading '+' character in URL without adding logic? Server.UrlEncode returns too much

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.0

This is what my URL looks like:

```
http://Server/Sales.aspx?Parm1=XZ AB+C (DE FH) IJ-KM NP
```

This is the value for the parameter `Parm1` in my URL:

```
Request.QueryString["Parm1"]
"XZ AB C (DE FH) IJ-KM NP"
```

With `Server.UrlEncode`:

```
Server.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["Parm1"])
= "XZ+AB+C+(DE+FH)+IJ-KM+NP"
```

And this is what the value should be:

```
"XZ AB+C (DE FH) IJ-KM NP"
```

Since the parameter can have many combinations with `+`, is there any way to read this parameter value without having to add logic to parse anything with the plus character?

Comment: Your URL should be `http://Server/Sales.aspx?Parm1=XZ AB%2BC (DE FH) IJ-KM NP`. Any `+` characters are interpreted as spaces, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) you can see a list of characters and there 'encoded equivalents'. As for your issue the '+' is `%2B`. So wherever `+` is in your URL, replace it with `%2B`. If you want your string to turn out like you stated then just use the `%2B` where a `+` is needed to be displayed, other than that you can just leave spaces.

Comment: I replace `+` with `%2B` and it works out fine. But I don't understand what you mean with `%2B%`

Comment: Ah, sorry this was my mistake. I meant to type `%2B` I added an extra `%` by mistake. Glad I could help you out man. Mark this as the answer if I answered your question!